# Javascript automatically deselects a selected radio box

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using the codes below to fetch data from database table without refreshing page. On page_one, I have this code:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function dis()
{
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","page_two.php",false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    document.getElementById("get_question").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
dis();
setInterval(function(){
    dis();
},1000);
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="get_question"></div>
```

**PHP**

This is on page_two

```
echo "
<form id='myform1' action='checkbox_no_refresh.php' method='post' >

   <h4>Question No 1</h4>
   <p style='font-size:14px; margin:0px 10px'>$question</p><br>

   A <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='A'> $option_a
   B <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='B'> $option_b
   C <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='C'>$option_c
   D <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='D'>$option_d   

  <button id='sub1' name='enter1' class='btn btn-success'>Save</button>
</form>  ";
```

The code fetches data as soon as the data gets to database without refreshing the page. But the problem now is that when I tick any **checkbox**, it will automatically **deselect** itself after the time I specify in the JavaScript. i.e 1 sec in this example. Hope someone will help me to solve this.

Comment: you're loading and overwriting a form ... of course the selection will be lost ... you'd need to save the selected item before the XHR, then re-select it after you clobber the form

Comment: You never run a `xhr.onreadystatechange` or `xhr.onload` Event. Poor use of AJAX, period. Use AJAX to get things that aren't going to be automatically loaded when the page is, and usually just for JSON data, then you can use JavaScript to create Elements on the DOM. You're not showing an attempt to accomplish the goal here, either. `CheckboxElement.checked = false;`.

Comment: well what do you expect to happen when you reload it every 1 sec, it cant both keep its state and reload a new state

Comment: Sorry I have little knowledge of javascript. @Jaromanda how can I save the selected item before XHR?

Comment: @PHPglue I beg you to show me example here, I have little knowledge of ajax.

Comment: There's more to in, but you'll want to [look at this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange).

Answer (score 0):

Save the states

```
var states = Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="checkbox[]"]'), function(el) {
    return {value: el.value, checked: el.checked};
});
```

Restore the states

```
states.forEach(function(x) {
    var value = x.value;
    var checked = x.checked;
    document.querySelector('input[name="checkbox[]"][value=' + value + ']').checked = checked;
})
```

Or, to code like a boss

```
let states = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="checkbox[]"]'), ({value, checked}) => ({value, checked}));
```

and

```
states.forEach(({value, checked}) => document.querySelector(`input[name="checkbox[]"][value=${value}]`).checked = checked);
```

Comment: Thank you @Jaromanda for your response. But where should I add these codes, because I added them on my javascript above and it did not work?

Comment: If i understand correctly. You would save before replacing the html and restore after. Of course there may be nothing to save the first time. So you'll need some logic

Comment: If I understand what you mean by before and after replacing html, I added the script for saving the selected item on the page that the form resides, and the script that will restore it on  page_one after my javascript above. But it didn't work. I am not sure if am placing the codes at the right place

Comment: Save.  Top of function dis. Restore.  Bottom of function dis. Of course the first run of dis has nothing to save and will cause an error unless you provide logic to avoid such errors

Comment: Actually.  Properly placed you don't need any further logic. My mistake